# Get the attribute name/string of a class with attribute

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, annotations

I have a classes called BillingActivity, DevelopmentActivity, ResearchActivity all implementing IActivity.

Somewhere in my app I enumerate a dll containing all types. Check wether typeof(IActivity).IsAssignable(type) if so I want to get string typeDescription = type.Attribute.Value or similar what I want is to put a attribute on a class OR on the above classes (depends what suggestions you make or what solutions are possible) like

```
[ActivityType = "Billing"].
public class BillingActivity {}
```

I do not want to get a instance of that type I just want to get the description(attribute `s value).

How can I do that? Can someone push me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom attribute with a single string property, tag your classes with it, then GetCustomAttributes to test a particular class is tagged with the attribute, and if it is you can read the property to pull the name you set.

```
public class ActivityTypeAttribute : Attribute 
{
 public Name { get; set; }
}

[ActivityType(Name="MyClass")]
public class MyClass { }

...
{
 ActivityTypeAttribute att = (ActivityTypeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyClass), typeof(ActivityTypeAttribute));

  Debug.Assert( att.Name == "MyClass" );
}
...
```

Edit - Also, please read this

[What's the simplest most elegant way to utilize a custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357109/whats-the-simplest-most-elegant-way-to-utilize-a-custom-attribute/3357145#3357145)

Comment: When I write this [ActivityType(Name="MyClass")] over MyClass it can not be resolved? Shouldn`t MyClass inherit from Attribute?

Comment: No, the custom attribute class is the only one who needs to inherit from Attribute. Can you post an example of what your seeing?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityType result =
  (ActivityType)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(this.GetType(), typeof(ActivityType));
```